# Cannot Resolve Method isChecked()

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou tentando utilizar o método isChecked() mas está dando a mensagem "Cannot Resolve Method IsCheked().Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_layout_lista_amc, parent, false);


        final AvaliacaoMensal mensalAmc = mensal.get(position);

        //pegando as referências das Views
        TextView potencial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.potencialLetra);
        TextView questao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questao);
        TextView titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo);

        //populando as Views
        potencial.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getPotencial()));
        questao.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getQuestao()));
        titulo.setText(String.valueOf(mensalAmc.getTitulo()));

        RadioGroup radioGroupAmc = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAmc);
        flag = mensal.get(position);

        radioGroupAmc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.sim:
                        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = group.isChecked();
                        // trata radioValor1
                        break;
                     case nao:
                       flag.radioButtonValues[1] = group.isChecked();
                        // trata radioValor2
                        break;
                    case na:
                        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = group.isChecked();
                        // trata radioValor3
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: O que é que você pretende fazer?

Comment: @ramaral Salvar se o radioButton foi ou não selecionado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse método não existe na classe RadioGroup.
O RadioButton que foi seleccionado é aquele cujo *id* está em `checkedId`.  Aquele *switch* já identifica qual é.

Se quer guardar na `flag` terá de fazer assim:

```
switch(checkedId) {
    case R.id.sim:
        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = true;
        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = false;
        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = false;
        // trata radioValor1
        break;
     case R.id.nao:
        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = false;
        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = true;
        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = false;
        // trata radioValor2
        break;
    case R.id.na:
        flag.radioButtonValues[0] = false;
        flag.radioButtonValues[1] = false;
        flag.radioButtonValues[2] = true;
        // trata radioValor3
        break;
}
```

Um RadioGroup só pode ter um RadioButton seleccionado, ao atribuir `true` a uma posição do *array* deve atribuir `false` às outras.
Há maneira de fazer isso de forma "mais elegante" mas na falta de mais informações é o que posso sugerir.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa instanciar os `RadioButton`, não só o `RadioGroup`.

Uma solução com um `RadioGroup` com três `RadioButton`.

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
final RadioButton[] rb = {
        (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sim),
        (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.nao),
        (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.na)
};
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.sim :
                    flag.radioButtonValues[0] = rb[0].isChecked();
                    break;
                case R.id.nao :
                    flag.radioButtonValues[1] = rb[1].isChecked();
                    break;
                case R.id.na :
                    flag.radioButtonValues[3] = rb[2].isChecked();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

O `RadioButton` não possui o método `isChecked()`, como consta na referência do `RadioButton` [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html), até porque o grupo possui vários botões, então não tem como saber se o grupo está todo selecionado, ficaria meio confuso até se existisse essa possibilidade.

Aí com os `RadioButton` instanciados tu consegue saber se ele está checado ou não com o método `idChecked()`.

Imagino que seja menos gambiarra dessa forma.

Pode ser melhorado, mas a intenção é essa.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas =)